Android Debugging without USB
I'm trying to use adb to run some experiments on an old phone of mine, but when connected via USB my computer doesn't recognize the phone as connected.  I'm now looking for other options/solutions, but I can't enable WIFI debugging as the phone is running Android 5.1 Lolipop. My computer is Ubuntu 20.04 Jammy, and the phone is a ZTE n9521 Boost Max+
The phone is charging, and I've tried all the USB connection options on the phone. I connected another phone and it works perfectly, so I doubt it's my computer or cables.
Anyone have any insight?

Make sure you are in the correct USB mode and USB debugging has been enabled. If you are in a USB mode to transfer files and such you wont be able to do debugging

Have you created a udev rule for your device? https://android.stackexchange.com/q/144966/2241
